# selected radiobutton to enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a  model that contains an enum called activitylevel and also a property called activityselected, I have a table of radiobuttons that are bound to the activityselected property, when a radiobutton is select I want to pass the corresponding enum to the activityselected property, in my view it says "ActivityLevel does not exist in the current context"? Just want to know eher i went wrong or is there a better way of doing this? 
Thanks for the help!!

Model:

```
  public class UserStats
    {
        public enum ActivityLevel
        {
            Sedentary,
            LightActivity,
            Moderate,
            Active,
            Extra
        }

        public Enum ActivitySelected { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
```

View:

```
      <table>
       <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ActivitySelected, ActivityLevel.Sedentary) Sedentary
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ActivitySelected,ActivityLevel.LightActivity) Light Activity
    </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ActivitySelected, ActivityLevel.Moderate) Moderate
    </td>
</tr>
            <tr>
         <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ActivitySelected,ActivityLevel.Active) Active
    </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.ActivitySelected, ActivityLevel.Extra) Extra
    </td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enum is declared inside the UserStats class, so you have to reference it with `UserStats.ActivityLevel.XXX` or move the enum out of the class (which is what I recommend)

Also, I would declare the enum member by its real type name, not as type Enum:

```
public enum ActivityLevel
{
   Sedentary,
   LightActivity,
   Moderate,
   Active,
   Extra
}

public class UserStats
{

    public ActivityLevel ActivitySelected { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
```